# Extending JDBC4Connection class

Tags: java, mysql

I'm searching for creating an extended class of JDBC4Connection to have my proper MySQL Connection JDBC class, and implement some methods. The JDBC4Connection constructor use a simple super(), so i refer to the constructor of parent class : ConnectionImpl.

This is :

```
 protected ConnectionImpl(String hostToConnectTo, int portToConnectTo, Properties info, String databaseToConnectTo, String url) throws SQLException
```

So, localhost for first, 3306 for second, my database name to fourth, and a complete connection string for the last. But for the "info", Properties typed, i don't know what to put in. The doc says :

**hostToConnectTo** - the hostname of the database server

**portToConnectTo** - the port number the server is listening on

**info** - a Properties[] list holding the user and password

**databaseToConnectTo** - the database to connect to

**url** - the URL of the connection

I tried to put keys "user" and "password" but that don't work.
Anyone know how to ?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to extend the class for MySQL connection only? Looks like a problem in your design. By the way, there is a [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Comment: Yes, i want to insert a method in for special type of prepared statement. I saw for the Properties class, but i dont know what to put in to etablish the connection. Doc says "user" and "password", but .put() for these keys don't seems to be interpreted by the connecting script

Comment: What do you want to insert in your `PreparedStatement`? Maybe that's your real problem and you're going for a big and tedious workaround.

Comment: i want the ? symbols take names, like :parameter1, but with the connection class, like : connection.prepareNamedParamsStmt()

Comment: Looks like you're in the tedious path. It would be better to create a wrapper class/interface that will handle a `PreparedStatement` and you can add/remove/change your `parameter1` instead of `?` and internally do all the changes for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java.html) of `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl`, user & password are fetched from the provided `Properties` like this:

```
this.user = info.getProperty(NonRegisteringDriver.USER_PROPERTY_KEY);
this.password = info.getProperty(NonRegisteringDriver.PASSWORD_PROPERTY_KEY);
```

which [are defined](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java.html) as

```
public static final String USER_PROPERTY_KEY = "user";
public static final String PASSWORD_PROPERTY_KEY = "password";
```

So your information is correct. Would you mind showing the code you actually wrote?

But me too, I think this may not be best approach for your problem. You should probably post this on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: Maybe ! i trying to do a thing like this : https://github.com/bnewport/Samples/blob/master/wxsutils/src/main/java/com/devwebsphere/jdbc/loader/NamedParameterStatement.java but with a use like connection.prepareStatement() and not like New prepareStatement(..., connection)

Comment: Actually i do this : Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put( "user", ... );
        p.put( "password", ...);

Comment: Ah well, that code seems to be independent of the underlying database and as such, reusable for the MySQL driver, too. So I suggest just using that code.

Comment: But if you insist - can you provide a bit more code and maybe the error message / stack trace?
And you're sure that if you just use the JDBC4Connection instead of your implemenation, that error does not occur?